# Is there a way to trigger a Power BI dataset refresh from a separate Azure tenant in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, powerbi, dataset, refresh, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to refresh a Power BI dataset in one Azure tenant by triggering it from another Azure tenant by using Azure Data Factory. I'm open to options.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the ClinetId ,ClientSecret and TenantId, you can call the REST API from any tenant.
The ClinetId and secret are tenant agnostic.
So that would work.